# Whats wrong with my matrix calculations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to solve this matrix for $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$

$$\pmatrix{
    -1 & -2& -3 \\
     3 & 2 & 1 \\
1& 1 & 1 \\
    2 & 4& 1 
    }* 
\pmatrix{
   x_1\\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
    }= \pmatrix{
   -6\\
6 \\
3 \\
7 \\ 
 }$$

Here are my calculations:

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
    -1 &  -2& -3 & -6 \\
    3 &  2& 1 & 6 \\
    1 &  1& 1 & 3 \\
    2 &  4& 1 & 7 \\    
    \end{array} \right)$$

row4 = row1*2 + row4 &&
row2 = row3*3 -row2

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
    -1 &  -2& -3 & -6 \\
    0 &  -1& 2 & -3 \\
    1 &  1& 1 & 3 \\
    0 &  0& -5 & -5 \\    
    \end{array} \right)$$

row4 = row4/-5 &&
row1 = row3 + row1

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
    0 &  -1& -2 & -3 \\
    0 &  -1& 2 & -3 \\
    1 &  1& 1 & 3 \\
    0 &  0& 1 & 1 \\    
    \end{array} \right)$$

row1 = row4*4 + row1

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
    1 &  1& -1 & 3 \\
    0 &  -1& 2 & -3 \\
    0 &  0& 1 & 1 \\
    0 &  0& 0 & 1 \\    
    \end{array} \right)$$

I get as a solution an unsolvable matrix; however, the matrix should be solvable. What was wrong with my calulations? I cannot see the problem.

Thx in advance!!!

Comment: You have $4$ equation for $3$ variables. *At most* the rank of the matrix is $3$ - which is your case.

Comment: Thx for your answer!!! Yes the rank is 3, however, I should solve the matrix for $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and in the last form, the matrix is not solvable, whereas the matrix has to be solvable...

Comment: Ok, to begin with. 1st step: row2 = row3*3-row2 has to have $3$, not $-3$

Comment: By the way, you can easily guess solution of this equation.

Comment: And the second element of row2 is also wrong in the first step.

Comment: @Juris How to guess the solution?

Comment: @maximus: it's $(1,1,1)$

Comment: Just try simple values that would satisfy one of the lines and check it on the others. But Ilya already gave it :)

Comment: Thx! Now I can see;) $x_1,x_2,x_3=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the third matrix row2=row3*3-row2,  $-1$ must be $1$ and $-3$ must be $3$. Thus the second row is $[0,~ 1,~ 2| ~3]$